# _tkinter.TclError: bad window path name".!dateentry.!entry"

Tags: python, tkinter, ttkbootstrap

An error was reported during program execution, so I used two files for testing. When calling test in the `test1` file, the `DateEntry` widget will disappear and an error will appear when clicked. I checked a lot, changed the style theme, updated the window, or created There is no `"_"` in the window name, but the error still occurs. The multi-select buttons and drop-down components in `ttkbootstrap` were also used in the original code, and they all functioned normally.The same problem occurs if I replace `ttkbootstrap.dataentry` with `tkcalende.dataentry` and I don't know where I went wrong.

[image]
the error

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\python\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "G:\python\lib\site-packages\ttkbootstrap\widgets.py", line 242, in _on_date_ask
    new_date = Querybox.get_date(
  File "G:\python\lib\site-packages\ttkbootstrap\dialogs\dialogs.py", line 1671, in get_date
    chooser = DatePickerDialog(
  File "G:\python\lib\site-packages\ttkbootstrap\dialogs\dialogs.py", line 601, in __init__
    self.root = ttk.Toplevel(
  File "G:\python\lib\site-packages\ttkbootstrap\window.py", line 454, in __init__
    self.transient(transient)
  File "G:\python\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2224, in wm_transient
    return self.tk.call('wm', 'transient', self._w, master)
_tkinter.TclError: bad window path name ".!dateentry.!entry"
```

test1.py

```
import ttkbootstrap as ttk
class Test1:
    def __init__(self):
        self.win1 = ttk.Window()
        self.win1.geometry("600x600")
        self.btn = ttk.Button(self.win1, text="click", command=self.test)
        self.btn.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.win1.mainloop()
    def test(self):
        import test
        test.Test()
Test1()
```

this is test.py

```
import ttkbootstrap as ttk
class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.win = ttk.Window()
        self.win.geometry("300x300")
        self.test = ttk.DateEntry(self.win,bootstyle="success")
        self.test.update()
        self.test.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.win.mainloop()
```

I want the `dataentry` widget to run normally after calling.

Comment: The test.py , you need Toplevel to  self.win = tk.Window()  and remove  self.win.mainloop(). Alsoo this too self.win1 = tk.Window()

Comment: Thank you very much!!! I did what you said and it worked successfully! Can you tell me why you need to use toplevel ? I don't quite understand why this is done.

Comment: Anyway, thank you very much for your advice! Helped me a lot!!!

Comment: `root.tk.Tk()` is  main window. If you want to open the windows, then use `tk.Toplevel`. Here is link https://www.pythontutorial.net/tkinter/tkinter-toplevel/

Comment: It is my pleasure to serve.